# How could I filter the result via wordnet synonyms /remove the negative synonyms from result

Tags: lucene.net, wordnet

Suppose I am trying to build an app which returns synonyms via Wordnet based on Lucent.net

A customized Synonym Analyzer and WordNet Synonym Engine built completed and it does work.

A synonym dictionay that downloaded from http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WNprolog-3.0.tar.gz is currently I am using,

but unfortunately, the result is not what I have been expacting sometime. due to some synonyms are about negative and might

cause horrible experience (see 'black' i.e),so here's my problem need to solve:

How could I filter/remove the negative synonyms from result.

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatful ...

Comment: Please provide a code sample illustrating the problem and what you have tried so far to solve it.